# Is there a leak in this C code?

Tags: c, malloc

Is there a leak in this C code?
Although the answer is coming correct, but just wanted to know if it is Ok to write like this:

```
// _mm_adds_epi16 : Adds the 8 signed 16-bit integers in a to the 8 signed 
//16-bit integers in b and saturates
__m128i t7=_mm_adds_epi16(  t5 ,t6  );
unsigned short *p= (unsigned short *)malloc(8);
p=(unsigned short *)&t7;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}
```

**Updated**

So now I am updating it as follows:

```
// _mm_adds_epi16 : Adds the 8 signed 16-bit integers in a to the 8 signed 
//16-bit integers in b and saturates
__m128i t7=_mm_adds_epi16(  t5 ,t6  );
unsigned short *p= (unsigned short *)malloc(8);
p=(unsigned short *)&t7;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}

 free(p);
```

Do I still have leak?

**What is the correct way to print t7**

Comment: If you don't later free (delete) the p, then YES!

Comment: Yes if you allocate and dont free it you will have a leak.

Comment: In general terms, you can use the Memcheck tool of Valgrind to help you detect memory leaks as well as memory-related errors. A short intro and quick guide is available here: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `malloc` in C needs to have some corresponding `free` which is reachable before termination. Any exception to this constitutes a memory leak.

You store the return of `malloc` in `p` and lose the pointer by overwriting it. As such there is no chance for the pointer to be freed. In your particular case, the `malloc` itself is redundant since you are not using the return in any way.

---

In response to your question of whether the new code has a memory leak, yes it does. `malloc` allocates memory and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. You are losing the pointer by overwriting its value then never using the allocated memory. Even worse you are now calling `free` on what appears to be an automatic variable which is undefined behaviour.

If the printing is working correctly, you can just do this:

```
__m128i t7 = _mm_adds_epi16(t5, t6);
unsigned short *p = (unsigned short *)&t7;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}
```

The `malloc` is redundant because you are not even using the memory it allocates.

Comment: Updated: Now I have put free(). is this OK now?

Comment: @gpuguy: The `malloc` is redundant and can be removed entirely. See the edit.

Comment: Now I got it, in my original code the original memory returned by malloc will never be freed (and which is never used), which is why leak.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a leak.  You immediately overwrite the pointer that's storing the address of the dynamically-allocated memory.  So that memory is no longer reachable.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Interesting, i have done this, and people with just as high a score count, give me issue with leaving it as an answer not a comment!

Comment: @trumpetlicks: Because there are differences between answers and comments. But this is definitely not a comment.

Comment: @trumpetlicks That may be so, and maybe you have been hard done by, but honestly how can you say this is not an answer?

Comment: Updated; Do I still have leak?

Comment: @gpuguy: Yes.  You are still immediately overwriting `p`.

Answer (score 0):

`free` will release any memory allocated by `malloc`.

```
unsigned short *p= (unsigned short *)malloc(8);
```

Here you have allocated 8 bytes of memory and have assigned that memory address to `p`.

```
p=(unsigned short *)&t7;
```

You just assigned a different memory address to `p`; the previous memory address (the one returned by`malloc`) has been overwritten. We no longer know the memory address where our 8 bytes have been allocated.

```
free(p);
```

Memory leak. It's not pointing to the memory allocated by `malloc` anymore.